# Drink Cold, Warm, or Hot water. Which one is better for constipation?

Tags: drinks, water-temperature, constipation

I want to ask, between cold, warm and hot water, which one is better to drink for relieving constipation?

Sources and references please.

Regards

Comment: what do you intend to do with the water? drink it? bathe in it?

Comment: Both cold and hot water will adopt the body temperature in minutes after drinking, so the effect of the temperature on constipation may be neutralized. Other that that, you can get the most reliable evidence, if you try yourself. I personally doubt, that the water temperature alone can help.

Comment: I doubt that too... But I'm asking in the context of "if I had to choose one between... those three" which one is better?

Comment: @Tomsofty33, this is easier to find that you may think: just try and see if there is any effect. Stick with a certain pattern for few days and then test another one. I personally can't imagine how cold water would help. But, it might help if the constipation is part of irritable bowel syndrome.

Comment: Yes that's true ... Then,is it no use for me to ask about it here? Because To test it I will have to wait for the constipation to happen first. Which I don't know when will it be....

Comment: Users here, including doctors, may not just know from the head what's better. So anyone would need to do a research instead of you. There may or may not be some studies about the topic. You can try searching using terms "hot" "cold" "constipation" "IBS, etc." But it's more likely you'll find this if you try on its own. Again, there may be much more important things that can help prevent constipation: consuming enough dietary fiber, physical activity, drinking enough water, etc.